# What should be the significance test when population size is unknown(know that it's more than 1M) and sample size is greater than 30?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, sample-size, population

I have a dataset with around 1M data. But, in real-life it should be more. From the dataset after first step processing for specific task, I got 50K data. Then I processed it again for a specific attribute value (continuous), got around 7K data successful. I was thinking of one-sample t-test considering population is unknown. Is it okay?
Again, what should be my sample size in this case? All 7K data (finally I had for a particular attribute) or 1000 of them?
(I read in some online sources that when the population is large, it should still be around 1000)https://tools4dev.org/resources/how-to-choose-a-sample-size/
https://www.qualtrics.com/experience-management/research/determine-sample-size/

I intend to test, whether the population mean is greater than the sample mean for that particular attribute.

I am a newbie in this field and would appreciate any kind of help from the community. TIA

Comment: A statistical tests is applied to test if a population parameter is equal to some given value, based on the data at hand and the hypothesis is formulated before observing the data.

Comment: Hi, @utobi, thanks for your reply. could you please answer the specific questions I asked?